# Given an array and group them as a possible sum

Tags: algorithm, partition-problem

Given an array and group them as a possible sum.

Input Only this array :  [1,2,3,4,5]
Output : {[5,1] [4,2]} {[3,2] [4,1]}

Is there any way to solve this problem without using nesting of for loop?

Comment: Recursive function with a single loop.

Comment: What is this `possible sum` value? Can this be anything?

Comment: And in the second example, why wasn't the grouping `[5]` included in groups that sum to 5?